# Visiting ip-address of site results in error

Tags: c, http, networking, dns, ipv4

I am trying to write a C Program that does a GET Request on a http site (because I havent yet researched how httpS requests work)
To start writing the code and test it I first need an http only website and its ip-address (because thats, what the socket api requires).
However whenever I do nslookup on the different http sites and then visit the sites over firefox with their respective ip addresses and port 80 I land on an error page and not the website I actually wanted.
How is that possible? Have I misunderstood a concept?
Examples:

```
nslookup lushbrightsilverpoem.neverssl.com 
yields the following ipv4: 18.66.122.106, 18.66.122.75, 18.66.122.5, 18.66.122.48

On firefox: <ip-address>:80/ has error result

nslookup example.com
yields the following ipv4: 93.184.216.34

On firefox: <ip-address>:80/ has 404 not found

nslookup info.cern.ch
yields the following ipv4: 188.184.21.108

On firefox: <ip-address>:80 has 404 not found
```

If this isnt the place to ask a question like this I will happily ask it somewhere else.
If I am missing something incredibly obvious then I apologize.
Thank you

Comment: The server could be checking HTTP header information and rejecting the request if the "host" is an IP and not a domain name.

Comment: Thank you! Tried the first few with postman with the appropriate host header and then it works.